# After installing Apache, PHP and MySQL I can't add extension to php.ini without Apache error

Tags: apache-2.2, php, extension

I have Windows XP OS.

Installed Apache 2.2.14, then PHP 5.2.12 (tested with phpinfo.php -> IT'S WORKS!)
Then I installed MySQL 5.1. And now, when I add `extension = php_mysql.dll` to php.ini and restart server, Apache tells me that he can't start (small window with "The requested operation has failed"). Even if I add only `extension = *smth*.dll` ---> the same thing. Apache just don't love my extensions. How to prove him, that they are cool and stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is your php extension directory set in php.ini and pointed to the right place?  Is your dll in the stated extensions directory?

http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

Comment: "extension_dir=c:\PHP\ext" --- in the php.ini
File php_mysql is in the c:\PHP\ext. File libmysql.dll is in the c:\PHP. PATH is with "c:\PHP\;". Mystic!..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Apache + PHP doesn't like the order in which extensions are loaded.

**Especially put *recode.so* at the front.**

What you want to do is remove all the extensions and then add a few at a time (or one at a time), for example, and check that Apache starts. When you find the one that crashes, add the rest, then restart, and finally move the crashing one to the front and restart. This is an issue with FreeBSD at least and I suspect it's the same.

Here's the order on my server with **recode** before **mysql** which you can try to mimic first

```
extension=recode.so
extension=fileinfo.so

extension=tidy.so
extension=tokenizer.so
extension=xmlreader.so
extension=xmlrpc.so
extension=bz2.so
extension=zip.so
extension=zlib.so
extension=mbstring.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pcre.so
extension=simplexml.so
extension=spl.so
extension=mysqli.so
extension=gd.so
extension=pdf.so
extension=filter.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=openssl.so



extension=ctype.so
extension=session.so
extension=sqlite.so
##extension=ldap.so
extension=bcmath.so
extension=calendar.so
extension=curl.so
extension=dom.so
extension=exif.so
extension=ftp.so
extension=xml.so
extension=wddx.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=hash.so
extension=iconv.so

extension=imap.so
extension=json.so


extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=posix.so
extension=pspell.so

extension=xmlwriter.so
```

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure your extension_dir is in the following format:

   ```
   extension_dir="DRIVE:/path/to/php"
   ```
2. make sure that `extension=php_pdo.dll` is uncommented and that you load sqlite ext right after. order is important.

   ```
   extension=php_pdo.dll
   ... < snip > ...
   extension=php_sqlite.dll
   ```

Comment: Source: http://www.mombu.com/php/php/t-35345-sqlite-wont-load-specified-module-not-found-1055232-last.html